# python regex to parse ifconfig output of different locales

Tags: python, regex, locale, ifconfig

I'm looking for a best way to parse IP and subnet details from `ifocnfig` output.

I don't want to search it based on the `inet addr` or `Mask:` because when a different locale is applied, the regex fails as the strings are changed.

Here is a sample text:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:F3:BE:18:1E
          inet addr:192.168.10.15  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:f3ff:febe:181e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:25457904 (24.2 Mb)  TX bytes:6540945 (6.2 Mb)
          Interrupt:20

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:12812 (12.5 Kb)  TX bytes:12812 (12.5 Kb)
```

I tried a couple of ways for doing it, e.g. using `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`, but couldn't find the best way. Need help on this.

Comment: @ also post your File in which you want to search

Comment: I tried the below:
 mac = re.search('\w\w:\w\w:.+\n', ifconfig)
parsedMac = mac.group()
print (parsedMac)
But that worked for only mac, didn't work for ip and subnet mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest using this regex:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\b
```

It should be used with `Multiline` option.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR6wT3/3).

The result is inside Group 1. See this [sample code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVlBYLS0zWUY1cnM):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\b', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:F3:BE:18:1E\n          inet addr:192.168.10.15  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\n          inet6 addr: fe80::218:f3ff:febe:181e/64 Scope:Link\n          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1\n          RX packets:39456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\n          TX packets:45730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000\n          RX bytes:25457904 (24.2 Mb)  TX bytes:6540945 (6.2 Mb)\n          Interrupt:20\n\nlo        Link encap:Local Loopback\n          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0\n          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host\n          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1\n          RX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\n          TX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0\n          RX bytes:12812 (12.5 Kb)  TX bytes:12812 (12.5 Kb)"
print re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Output:

```
 [u'192.168.10.15', u'192.168.10.255', u'255.255.255.0', u'127.0.0.1', u'255.0.0.0']
```

Comment: This helps! Thx a lot. I was looking for extracting both IP and Mask also.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. Now, it also extracts  Masks and Bcasts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
tempstr='blah blah 172.16.13.35 blah blah 23.85.85.94'

matches = re.findall(r'\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+', tempstr) 
for match in matches:
    print match
```

This code will print all the ip found in given string tempstr.
output of program is 
**172.16.13.35
23.85.85.94**

Comment: This will also capture `Mask` and `Bcast` values. I guess OP does not want them.

Comment: This is perfect! And serves my purpose. Thx a lot!